# Strange NullPointerException with Hibernate and fetch type LAZY

Tags: java, hibernate

In our application I want to generate a report. Therefore multiple instances of `Foo` and associated `Bar` entities are loaded (but not changed). The relevant data is taken from the entities and stored in report beans for actual report generation. When the transaction is closed and Hibernate flushes errors occur (see below).

Besides other attributes, `Foo` holds a reference to  `Bar`. This is an extract of both classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
public class Foo {

    @Column(name = "BAR_ID")
    private Long barId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Bar bar;

    public Long getBarId() {
        return barId;
    }

    public void setBarId(Long barId) {
        this.barId = barId;
    }

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    // no setter for "bar"

    // other attributes
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "BAR")
public class Bar {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bar", fetch = LAZY)
    private List<Foo> foos;

    // no getter/setter for "foos"

    // other attributes
}
```

The whole application with various other operations (including creation, editing, deleting of the aforementioned entities) works flawless, but upon report creation I get strange errors:

1)

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: Found two representations of same collection: Bar.foos; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: Bar.foos
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:216)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:681)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:563)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at de.ba.wws.aop.TransactionTimeAspect.setTransactionTime(TransactionTimeAspect.java:20)
[...]
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Found two representations of same collection: Bar.foos
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Collections.processReachableCollection(Collections.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.FlushVisitor.processCollection(FlushVisitor.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processValue(AbstractVisitor.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractVisitor.processEntityPropertyValues(AbstractVisitor.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.onFlushEntity(DefaultFlushEntityEventListener.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEntities(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:231)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:102)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    ... 119 more
```

2)

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.prepareEntityFlushes(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:155)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.flushEverythingToExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:555)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at de.ba.wws.aop.TransactionTimeAspect.setTransactionTime(TransactionTimeAspect.java:20)
    [...]
```

3) `NullPointerException` in `org.hibernate.internal.util.compare.ComparableComparator.compare(Comparable, Comparable)` (both arguments `null`). (I cannot provide a stack trace for this one as I cannot produce it at the time of writing.)

I get one of the three above errors (or no error at all) upon executing the report. Sometimes I need to call the report multiple times to produce an error, sometimes the first run already generates one. I'm not able to figure out what might cause this behaviour.

The only workaround I found is to switch the fetch type of *both* shown attributes to `EAGER`. Then everything works well, but is not desired as the prefetched data amount is high.

Every hint is welcome and if you need any further details, please let me know.

We are currently using Hibernate 4.3.8. I locally tried newer versions (4.3.11 shows the same problems), but upgrading to 5.x is a major task and can only be accomplished in a short timeframe if anyone can assure us that the problem is fixed (if it's actually a Hibernate issue) in 5.x.

Comment: Do you use POJOs to move data around (as opposed to passing `Foo` and `Bar` entities directly to the report generation logic)? Is the Hibernate session closed when the report generation starts?

Comment: Can you provide some information about your DAO? In my opinion there is a database column missing, somewhere you have to define the foreign key column. I would  try @JoinColumn(name="FK Column Name")

Comment: @burubum The data is transfered to POJOs (beans) which are passed to the report generator. I'm not sure whether the session is closed before, but at least it is flushed before (with flush throwing the exceptions).

Comment: @M46 I guess the FK relation is extracted by Hibernate "magic" (I'm no expert in Hibernate) related to the according ID column (added `barId` to code example).

Comment: Please post getters and setters for relevant properties.

Comment: @Lesiak Added them to source. (No special implementations or annotations there.)

Comment: Well, if I get this right your mapping can't work. Take a look at https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#example.collection.mapping.annotations At 7.2 is stated that if you do not describe any mapping hibernate is generating a mapping from the table names. I cannot imagine that this will work.

Comment: @dosenfant If so, the problem is probably unrelated to the report, it should happen whenever you query these tables. I would try to isolate the logic and make it reproducible. Some people say that may depend on duplicated setters/getters, not sure if it can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally understood what is/was the problem:

As the report generation takes a lot of time due to the huge amount of data, generation was *parallelized*. Within the processing portion in the executor threads some objects were referenced from the `bean`---which were actually still `Hibernate` managed entities---and `Hibernate` could not resolve those `proxies` (as the `session` was not valid inside the `threads`).

Strange is the fact, that those problems (actually real exceptions!) were just visible when setting `Hibernate` logging to `trace` and the resulting exceptions were not that understandable as the underlying ones!

This also explains, why the report generation worked gracefully when fetch modes were set to `EAGER`.

My current solution now is to make sure all needed data from the entities (within the `beans`) are fetched *before* actual multi-threaded processing.